# is it possible to decide model without any data?

Tags: data-science-model, model-selection

Today I just faced a very unique demand from my superior. He asked me whether I can make a model first before we gather the data for training because we don't have any data yet. 
I was utterly confused about what to do with this. Did anyone have any suggestion how should I approach modelling without any data at all? Thanks

Comment: Is he asking for a proof-of-concept, or for you to build a computational framework for model building and evaluation, which you can later plug real data into? Without data, you could build a model-builder, but I'm not sure how you could build the model itself without any training data - you'll never know if your model reflects reality in any way or not. Do you have domain knowledge that can be leveraged in some way?

Comment: Nope all I know is that it is machinery and yes he is asking for model not model-builder. I have search for a similar dataset in kaggle, NASA everywhere and there is none.

Comment: Then you should be asking the domain experts for more information e.g. what issues are they having with their machinery? Or what problem do they want to solve?

Comment: I c thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a very strange situation in real world companies who nowadays want to build data science applications and other data related stuff, but without enough historical data (or none at all).

In this case, defining what a model is might help you, so:

- are you/your superior considering only ***machine learning models***? In that case, **you need** the **data** to train with
- are you also considering a less sophisticated approach like ***rules-based models*** first? In that case, you can generate (i.e. programm it) such rules based on business knowledge before going directly into the machine learning pipeline, for which you need data

**Another option**, which I used once to check some ideas in advance (before having data) is to **simulate some data** based on the **known data distributions** which you know you might have in a near future; for instance, you might want to simulate clients ages, clientes accounts amounts... from other banks stored in some open-data platform. 
In this case, you can model your data with for instance a [kernel density estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html#kernel-density), to generate afterwards some synthetic samples. Below you can find what I onced made with a similar situation, where the orange bars are the open data retrieved with variables similar to what I would eventually have in my company (in this case I needed ages for each marital status, and I found it for a bank of a similar country) and used to generate the kernel density data generator (blue line):

[image]

Comment: It is an intresting idea. My superior ask for machine learning model though, but maybe I can suggest rule based-models first. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well you must first consider **what type of data**, **the category of algorithm**, and **what branch of machine learning you will be doing**... for example:

- unsupervised time series on stocks
- supervised categorical classification of images
- etc.

After this, you could select a few suitable algorithms for your use-case,(e.g. regression, random forests, or other suitable methods) and then generate some **simulated data** which would roughly approximate the data once you have it.

You could then train and test the model on the simulated datasets, in preparation for the collection of real data.

At this stage, it sounds like you need to **gather more information** about the use-case so you know the direction to develop.

Comment: I think for simulated data we need to at least have a bit of data right? Is it possible to simulate data with no clue at all? Do you mind sharing how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, as I also explained in my other answer, you need to have some other (presumably) similar data source (with similar distributions) so you can simulate based on this similar data

Comment: It really depends on what you're building it for. For example, I worked on a project which was looking to analyse blood vessels. What is a blood vessel? It is broadly a cylinder. So in this case, I simulated 3d cylinders with diameters similar to that of human vessels, and then increased the complexity of the simulation (i.e. add bends, variations in wall thickness etc.). I had the luxury of real data to build it with, but you can start with your best guess e.g. sine-waves / distributions (as mentioned by @GermanCM) / images / 3d shapes / or whatever you will expect to analyse